# Read the content of the string only after specific keyword in python

Tags: python, split

I have a string as

```
WARC-Type: warcinfo
WARC-Date: 2016-05-08T21:06:17Z
WARC-Filename: CC-MAIN-20160428161506-00000-ip-10-239-7-51.ec2.internal.warc.wet.gz
WARC-Record-ID: <urn:uuid:eb7cd794-cb78-4f73-8b35-f676ecc7ce23>
Content-Type: application/warc-fields
Content-Length: 256

Software-Info: ia-web-commons.1.0-SNAPSHOT-20160413104958
Extracted-Date: Sun, 08 May 2016 21:06:17 GMT
robots: classic
isPartOf: CC-MAIN-2016-18
operator: CommonCrawl Admin
description: Wide crawl of the web for April 2016
publisher: CommonCrawl
```

what I wanted is I want  to read only the content after content-length: ....   There can be similar other string as well in the list []. so I want to loop through the list where each list member has something like above header and I just wanted to read the content after the content-length. I tried to skip the first 5-6 lines. however it may not be always the case of constant line in header but is sure to have content after Content-Length.

How can I read just the content after Content-Length.

expected output is :

```
Software-Info: ia-web-commons.1.0-SNAPSHOT-20160413104958
Extracted-Date: Sun, 08 May 2016 21:06:17 GMT
robots: classic
isPartOf: CC-MAIN-2016-18
operator: CommonCrawl Admin
description: Wide crawl of the web for April 2016
publisher: CommonCrawl
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

Make two loops: one looks for "Content-Length:" in the present line.  Exit the loop when you find that trigger phrase.

The second loop simply prints the remainder of the text, without testing the contents at all.

Does that handle your issue?